# How to check network status in iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reachability

I have setup some methods to check network status in my app.

In my `viewDidLoad` method I call `initNetworkCheck`:

```
[self initNetworkCheck];
[super viewDidLoad];
if(internetActive == NO){     
    compose.enabled = NO;
}
```

So I want to check on startup if the hardware has internet connection. The problem is it gives me always NO but internetActive is actually YES when I log it.

```
//[[[[[[network check methods
-(void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice{
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable:{
            self.internetActive = NO; 
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:{
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:{
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus){
        case NotReachable:{
            self.hostActive = NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:{
            self.hostActive = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:{
            self.hostActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

}
-(void)initNetworkCheck{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];

    hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"] retain];
    [hostReachable startNotifier];
}
//]]]]]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make use of Apple's Reachability class. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) is a sample App by Apple.

> The Reachability sample application
>   demonstrates how to use the
>   SystemConfiguration framework to
>   monitor the network state of an iPhone
>   or iPod touch. In particular, it
>   demonstrates how to know when IP can
>   be routed and when traffic will be
>   routed through a Wireless Wide Area
>   Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE
>   or 3G.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the following:

```
typedef enum
{
    NoConnection = 0,
    WiFiConnected,
    WWANConnected
} NetworkStatus;

NetworkStatus getNetworkStatus ( )
{
    struct sockaddr_in nullAddress;

    bzero(&nullAddress, sizeof(nullAddress));
    nullAddress.sin_len = sizeof(nullAddress);
    nullAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SCNetworkReachabilityRef ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*) &nullAddress);

    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(ref, &flags);

    if (!(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable))
        return NoConnection;

    if (!(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired))
        return WiFiConnected;

    if (((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnDemand) ||
        (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnTraffic)) &&
        !(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsInterventionRequired))
        return WiFiConnected;

    if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN) == kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)
        return WWANConnected;

    return NoConnection;
}
```

I forget exactly where, but there's an example in the SDK somewhere that this is based on.

**EDIT:** looks like Nick found it... :)