# How to check if any network available in OS X app?

Tags: xcode, macos, networking, network-programming

In my App, I wanted to check if there any type of existing network available in current OS X system. Ethernet or Internet or Wifi or 3G-card or any other type of network communication.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

---

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662298...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662298/how-to-check-network-status-in-iphone-app)

Thank [bdash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1991710/bdash) and [cody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971144/cody)! I do my homework and found another answer above. But that is for iPhone, I make some modification below.

```
- (BOOL)isAnyNetworkExist
{
    struct sockaddr_in nullAddress;

    bzero(&nullAddress, sizeof(nullAddress));
    nullAddress.sin_len = sizeof(nullAddress);
    nullAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SCNetworkReachabilityRef ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*) &nullAddress);

    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(ref, &flags);
    CFRelease(ref);     /* !!! */

    AMCDebug(@"Flag: 0x%08X", flags);
    if (0 != (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsIsLocalAddress))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I check the "*kSCNetworkFlagsIsLocalAddress*" ONLY, but I am not sure if this OK.

I tried the flag when I remove all network connection and it returned 0x07.

Comment: This is either a duplicate of either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627058/how-to-determine-internet-connection-in-cocoa or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367927/get-a-list-of-all-available-network-interfaces-en0-en1-en2-etc-with-cocoa/. It's not clear from the question which is most appropriate.

Comment: No, the link uses shell command to do so. What I wanted is the way in app runtime way. Perhaps this may work [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021095/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021095/using-cocoa-objective-c-get-currently-connected-networks-security-type-in-ma/4024962#4024962). I will keep searching...

Comment: None of the linked questions require shell commands. Every single one of them has answers pointing you at the various SystemConfiguration APIs.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I miss your first link! I will try Reachability right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I put my further homework above. What about your opinion?

Comment: I noticed that this question is marked duplicate. The duplicated target is WRONG! If truly duplicated, it would be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662298/how-to-check-network-status-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [SCNetworkReachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html). In general you will create reachability object and add it to run loop and you'll get callback when it will be reachable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627058/how-to-determine-internet-connection-in-cocoa) post for details.
Also take a look at [SCNetworkConfiguration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html): you can take a walk through all interfaces in system and see if any of them is connected.
And also you can take a look at [SCDynamicStore](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStore/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008287). There is an [example](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Macnetworkprog/2006/Oct/msg00007.html) in apple mailing list.

Comment: I do not need something that complex. What I want to know is if there is ANY network available. For example, a ethernet card is connected to a hub, which cause the network card be the status "linked", and this repersents an available network.

Comment: take a look at the second answer in the link I gave you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627058/how-to-determine-internet-connection-in-cocoa

Comment: In general I don't know simple way to do this. There is only complex or not so complex :)

Comment: Haha, maybe you're right. I wonder if there is a general way in UNIX-like system.

Comment: ping through exec and check the result? :)

Comment: Haha, ping who? I put my further homework above. What about your opinion?

Comment: I don't think that would work. I'd rather use kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable flag, but you are trying to check null address. Do you know what should it return? About your exclamation marks - it is safe to release it here SCNetworkReachabilityFlags is just a uint32_t and they already filled in. About return value - I'd rather return just comparison result. And what was you asking for?)

Comment: I am trying to check null address, or, ANY address. Which means I do not know the target address of any devices. I simply want to check whether there is at lease one available network connection present in local computer.   Hmmm... I am afraid I did not describe my request clearly. My falut.